# C# - MVVM Way to Handle Calls into Event Handler while in that Handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I ran into this simple case of a control handler being called while in that handler, which is not a new problem for me, but my simple solution did not pass code review. I searched for similar SO questions, and found a couple of similar questions, but am not sure if they were the best solution.

I had a simple textbox on a grid control that I was using to seek to rows in a large dataset displayed in a datagrid. The plan was to use carriage return as the trigger to do the search, so "AcceptsReturn" was set to "True" in the textbox. Simple MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestXaml.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="250">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White"  Height="100" Width="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="GoToLabel" Content="Go To Packet ID:" Margin="12, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="GoToTarget" Width="75" TextChanged="GoToTarget_TextChanged" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Windows;  
using System.Windows.Controls;  

namespace TestXaml  
{  
    class SomeDataViewModel  
    {  
        public SomeDataViewModel() { }  
        public bool PacketIndexFor(int packetId, ref int packetIndex)  
        {  
            packetIndex = packetId;  // Just a dummy.  
            return true;  
        }  
    }  

    /// <summary>  
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml  
    /// </summary>  
    public partial class MainWindow :   
    {  
        private SomeDataViewModel someDataViewModel;  // The data viewmodel.  
        private bool inGoToTarget = false;  // Stop recursion into goToTarget_TextChanged.  

        public MainWindow()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
        }  

        private void GoToTarget_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            if (inGoToTarget)  // If we are already handling a text-changed event, get out.  
            {  
                return;  
            }  

            inGoToTarget = true;  
            TextBox goToTarget = sender as TextBox;  
            if (null == goToTarget)  
            {  
                inGoToTarget = false  
                return;  
            }  

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(goToTarget.Text))  
            {  
                inGoToTarget = false;  
                return;  
            }  

            string enteredTextNoReturn = goToTarget.Text;  
            if (-1 != goToTarget.Text.IndexOf("\r\n"))  
            {  
                enteredTextNoReturn = goToTarget.Text.Substring(0, goToTarget.Text.Length - 2);  // Strip "\r\n"  
            }  

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(enteredTextNoReturn))  // Was just carriage return.  
            {  
                // Next line will cause a call to GoToTarget_TextChanged from inside GoToTarget_TextChanged.  
                goToTarget.Text = "";  // Get rid of carriage return.  
                inGoToTarget = false;  
                return;  
            }  

            goToTarget.Text = enteredTextNoReturn;  // Get rid of the carriage return.  

            int packetId = -1;  
            if (int.TryParse(enteredTextNoReturn, out packetId))  
            {  
                int packetIndex = -1;  
                if (someDataViewModel.PacketIndexFor(packetId, ref packetIndex))  
                {  
                    // Set a slider or control value that will make the requested packet display.  
                }  
            }  

            inGoToTarget = false;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Note that to "solve" my problem, I just added a bool to the class, "inGoToTarget" and set/unset it so that if I am in the handler and try to re-enter it, the handler will just return.

Realizing that the call to re-enter the handler happens from inside the handler, and thus in the same thread, what would be the best-practice way to avoid this problem using .Net 4.5 or later?

I "fixed" it by avoiding it altogether - I decided I liked the behavior of the go-to happening as I typed the numbers, and so just removed the "AcceptsReturn" property. That meant I could remove the code that checked for carriage return and avoid setting the value from inside the handler.

Comment: Writing all your logic inside an event handler is not a good idea. There's no reentrancy involved here. This method seems to be doing 2 or 3 different things - it should be broken into two or three different methods.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - I can see that. In my case, the result of the logic is to update a control in the view, so how would you recommend I change the code? I assume some async operation in the viewmodel? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: There's no reentrancy, asynchrony or concurrency here. Just modifying the UI from inside the UI's event handlers. Such problems arise when you check the UI controls for data instead of your data collections/model. The other problem is that you modify your own textbox but forget to check for your modifications. The end result is that the code is unreadable and accidentally recursive

Comment: As a quick fix, disable the textbox while you work on it but please, please refactor the method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Got it - thanks!